# ListTile Switch in flutter how to change the shape and size of the button alone

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-slider

Now making some changes at the calling part it worked

[image]

I have Edited the source as per the answer mentioned below, nothing changes the output remains the same

[image: Here are the changes that I made]

Here is the output: it is now in oval shape, I need to change it in to rectangular shape.

[image: Here is the output: it is now in oval shape, I need to change it in to rectangular shape]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT4Og.png)

I'm using [list_tile_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/list_tile_switch) and here is the code-snippet

```dart
  ListTileSwitch(
      value: _value,
      leading: Icon(Ionicons.moon),

      onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
      _value = value;
      });
      },
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.comfortable,
      switchType: SwitchType.cupertino,
      switchActiveColor: Colors.indigo,
      title: Text('Dark theme'),
      )
```

Comment: can you include what are you trying to archive ?

Comment: I was using ListTileSwitch widget in flutter, and it worked perfectly and I need to change defaulf oval chape to a rectangle shape and also need to increse the size

the above is the current code. 

refernce: https://pub.dev/packages/list_tile_switch

Comment: Please clarify which shape and size, for more read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have edited the above post with a new link, it contains the current output image.
I need shape to be in rectangle and wants to know how to change the size

Comment: That's an in build future can be edited on source code, but it would be easy to create using custom widget with `AnimatedContainer,Stack`, you want i can share alternative way

Comment: please share @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is just editing source code but not recommended, but we can make it local and edit the code and import to use it.

You need to comment this part

[image]

You can copy the full code and create another dart file to save it. and just import it to use.

Comment: Nothing changes it remains as the same

Comment: do `flutter clean` and rebuild again.

Comment: it worked after removing 
     visualDensity: VisualDensity.comfortable,
      switchType: SwitchType.cupertino,
      switchActiveColor: Colors.indigo,